# boost deserialization problem of juce::String with XML wide archive

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm using boost::serialize to serialize a document wherein I use f.i. a juce::String. Like so:

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize( Archive & ar, const unsigned int version )
{
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("title", m_docTitle);
    ...
}
```

For boost::serialize to accept juce::String as a primitive type I did:

```
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

template<class IStream>
inline IStream& operator >> (IStream& stream, juce::String& s)
{
    std::wstring t;
    stream >> t;
    s = juce::String(t.c_str());
    return stream;
}

BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(juce::String, boost::serialization::primitive_type)
```

which compiles nicely. Serialization works fine, I get the entry in the XML:

```
<title>DocumentTitle</title>
```

as it should be. However when deserializing I can trace in the >> operator that the string returned is:

```
"DocumentTitle</title>"
```

i.e. some of the XML has been "chewed up", which later of course leads to an "input stream error" exception.

The oddest part is though that I had this working up until a week ago... :( and I have no idea what makes it NOT work now...

Edit: A little example code that shows reproduces the behavior, only dependency is boost:

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/xml_woarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_wiarchive.hpp>
#include <sstream>

class JuceString
{
public:
    JuceString(const std::wstring& str = L"") : m_str(str) {;}
    JuceString(const JuceString& other) : m_str(other.m_str) {;}
    JuceString& operator = (const JuceString& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            m_str = other.m_str;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    const wchar_t* toWideCharPointer() const {
        return m_str.c_str();
    }

private:
    std::wstring m_str;
};

template <class OStream>
OStream& operator<< (OStream& stream, const JuceString& stringToWrite)
{
    return stream << stringToWrite.toWideCharPointer();
}

template <class IStream>
IStream& operator>> (IStream& stream, JuceString& s)
{
    std::wstring t;
    stream >> t;
    s = JuceString(t.c_str());
    return stream;
}

BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(JuceString, boost::serialization::primitive_type)


class Doc
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize( Archive & ar, const unsigned int version )
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("title", m_title);
    }

public:
    Doc() {;}
    Doc(const std::wstring& s) : m_title(s) {;}

private:
    JuceString m_title;
};


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::wstringstream stream;
    {
        // Serializing document
        Doc doc(L"DocumentTitle");
        boost::archive::xml_woarchive oa(stream);
        oa << boost::serialization::make_nvp("Document", doc);
    }
    {
        // Deserializing document
        Doc doc;
        try
        {
            boost::archive::xml_wiarchive ia(stream);
            ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("Document", doc);
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using the text archive instead works just fine both ways...

Comment: Can you reduce this to a one-file example we can all compile and run on our workstations? To try it out right now requires a bit of fiddling for every reader who wants to try it. It's nearly there, but with `int main()` and a few `#includes` you would have a *great* [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and probably quite a few more people interested in trying it.

Comment: It's a bit complicated as the juce library would be needed... but I'll fix one with that as premise.

Comment: Ok, updated the question with code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it to work (for XML archive nota bene), by using boost basic_xml_grammar to parse the string in operator>> , like so:

```
typedef boost::archive::basic_xml_grammar<wchar_t> xml_wgrammar;

template <class IStream>
IStream& operator>> (IStream& stream, JuceString& s)
{
    std::wstring t;
    xml_wgrammar grammar;
    if (!grammar.parse_string(stream, t))
    {
        boost::serialization::throw_exception(
            boost::archive::xml_archive_exception(boost::archive::xml_archive_exception::xml_archive_parsing_error)
        );
    }
    s = JuceString(t.c_str());
    return stream;
}
```

That will make sure that the string is parsed correctly.

Comment: +1, I learned something from this. I think you should accept this answer over mine since this seems like the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `operator >>`

When you do:

```
std::wstring t;
stream >> t;
```

You read in until the next space. In XML that's after the closing tag, so you are reading part of the stream that boost expects to be able to read there.

The solution is to either force an extra space into the output, or modify `operator >>` to refuse to read anything like '<'. My guess would be that previously you had an extra space in the string you were saving and restoring.

Assuming you can set/assign from `std::wstring` and get some kind of raw value that can be used to create std::wstring this works on my machine:

```
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>
```

...

```
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

  template<class Archive>
  void load(Archive & ar, JuceString & j, const unsigned int version)
  {
    std::wstring tmp;
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("value", tmp);
    j = tmp;
  }

  template<class Archive>
  void save(Archive & ar, const JuceString & j, const unsigned int version)
  {
    const std::wstring tmp(j.toWideCharPointer());
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("value", tmp);
  }

} // namespace serialization                                                                                                                                            
} // namespace boost                                                                                                                                                    
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(JuceString)
```

This escapes the need to write an `operator >>` and lets the boost handle reading/writing the wstring to the archive directly. You only need to write it once too, so it avoids the duplication issues and then you can use `JuceString` as often as you like.

Comment: Thing is, this has worked fine before. And besides, the std::basic_istream operator for std::wstring works pretty much the same way, so then std::wstring should show the same problem, which it doesn't.

Comment: I think there's a nicer fix actually, hang on

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I didn't have a space before either... :(

Comment: @Robert - updated, by splitting the load/save you can let the boost archive worry about how to read a `std::wstring` for you.

Comment: @awoodland: Appreciated, but that is exactly what I didn't want. Since I'm going to use plenty of juce::String throughout the serialization, this approach will soon become tedious and error prone... Oh, and besides, in (actual) juce::String there is no std::wstring to use (my example uses std::wstring for sake of simplicity)

Comment: @robert - is there a constructor from `std::wstring` though? and the `const wchar_t *` method exists in the real version?

Comment: @robert - 3rd time lucky? Split it as a free function that should avoid the tedious/error prone bit.

Comment: @awoodland: Yes, there is, or rather from wchar_t* and yes there is the const wchar_t* method in the real version. Regarding free function, yep, I did that first (before I tried the "primitive" way), but when the "primitive" way worked I ditched the free function splitting (mind you, there are several other juce classes that I fixed that way)...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if have an answer for you, but when comparing the code in my workspace to serialize out ATL CString I have the following:

```
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, CString & s, const unsigned int file_version) 
{
    std::wstring ss( s );
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(ss);
    s = ss.c_str();
}
```

I wonder if you could do something like this in your `operator <<` - unsure if this solution is applicable to you or not. Apologies in advance if not.

Comment: Thnx, it does indeed work, but then it adds (using XML) an extra element "ss", which is what I would like to avoid. Purely cosmetically though... :)